# CSS anchor and button stylized the same, but different sizes

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to style the anchor and the buttons the same way, but they are rendering with different sizes, I would appreciate some help!
This is my code

```css
.button-delete {
  background: rgb(253, 75, 75);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #000;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;  
}

.button-read {
  background: rgb(122, 122, 122);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;  
}
```

```html
<button class="button-delete">button delete</button>
<a class="button-read">button read</a>
```

Comment: Different sizes? Different length, height?

Comment: @prettyInPink Why are you changing the code which the OP posted? Also if the question title contains some discrepancies with the code, this changes the question completely and makes answers based on the original code seem wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define a `width`, so the width by default adjusts to the content (text). As soon as you do, they have the same size:

```css
.button-delete {
  background: rgb(253, 75, 75);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #000;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;  
  width: 200px;
}

.button-read {
  background: rgb(122, 122, 122);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;  
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-delete">button delete</button>
<button class="button-read">button read</button>
```

Comment: apologies, I didn't modify the existing code, simply added a working snippet for visuals, only CSS was provided, so I quickly included html, but based on those classes I both added button tags instead of the title suggesting, one of them should be an anchor tag. I did quickly after update the included html. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

An anchor element is `display: inline` by default, and button element is `display: inline-block` by default.

To have an anchor element and a button element respect the same sizing(padding): Set the anchor element to `display: inline-block;`